# Programa que receba uma série de notas precisa desconsiderar uma entrada inválida

Tags: java, array, validação

> Faça um programa que receba uma série de notas de alunos e depois as imprima. Entretanto, o programa não pode aceitar notas maiores que 100 ou menores que 0. Se o usuário digitar alguma nota errada, deve conseguir digitar novamente.

O código até o momento está assim:

```
public class notaMenorCem
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    int notaAluno [] = new int[5];
    for (int i=0; i<notaAluno.length; i++)
    {
      notaAluno[i] = Entrada.leiaInt ("Digite a nota: ");
      {
        if(notaAluno[i] <0 || notaAluno[i] >100)
        {
          System.out.println("Nota inválida, digite novamente:");
        }
      }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<notaAluno.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.println("Nota do aluno " +i+ ":"+notaAluno[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

O usuário recebe o aviso por inserir uma nota maior que 100 porém ela fica registrado igual, o que está faltando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou não fazer a atribuição se a validação falhar, por isso coloquei um `continue`. E faltou voltar o contador para trás se o item não for inserido, para manter o sincronismo.

Faltou validar quando um valor digitado não é um número, se fizer esse teste a aplicação quebrará, mas não vou corrigir isso.

Faltou outras coisas menos relevantes.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int notaAluno [] = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < notaAluno.length; i++) {
            var nota = sc.nextInt();;
            if (nota < 0 || nota > 100) {
                System.out.println("Nota inválida, digite novamente:");
                i--;
                continue;
            }
            notaAluno[i] = nota;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < notaAluno.length; i++) System.out.println("Nota do aluno " + i + ":" + notaAluno[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/e2pIXW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qfilznve-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/LoopInvalidData.java).